# A woman who prays yom tov shemona esrei on chol hamoed

Tags: halacha, tefilla, shemoneh-esrei, mistakes, chol-hamoed

Does a woman who prays yom tov shemona esrei on chol hamoed have to repeat?

Comment: Do you have any reason to suspect a women and man would be different in this regard?

Comment: Phillip, welcome to Mi Yodeya! I recommend that you [edit] this question to explain more about what you think the relevant issues are and what motivates this question. That will make it much more likely that you'll get answers that address your point of curiosity. Please take a look at our [How to Ask](http://yodeya.com/help/how-to-ask) page for tips on how to pose an especially answerable and valuable question. Finally, please consider [registering](http://yodeya.com/users/login) your account, which will give you access to more of the site's features.

Answer (score 1):

Rabbi Ovadiah Yosef rules (Yechavveh Da'at 5:37) that she should not repeat it, but must recite the entire 19 blessings including Ya'aleh veYavo that she should have said to begin with. He reasons that since Chazal enacted to recite a full 19-blessing-prayer on Chol haMoed, one does not fulfill one's obligation with only 7 blessings. Thus the initial mistaken prayer is void.

His ruling that the initial mistaken prayer is void appears to apply to anyone who said such a prayer, whatever their gender may be.

Rabbi Moshe Feinstein has a similar argument in Igrot Moshe OC 4:21:3, explicitly applying the ruling to days of Chol haMoed which fall on Shabbat as well.